# sh: sysctl: command not found ROOT hadd

Tags: macos, command-line

I want to do `hadd` of two `.root` files. `hadd` is a function of the `ROOT` software library, which produces `.root` files. When I do `hadd` I get the error:

```
$ hadd -f FinalFileName.root IndividualFileNames*.root

sh: sysctl: command not found
hadd Target file: FinalFileName.root
hadd compression setting for all output: 1

 *** Break *** floating point exception
[/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib] _sigtramp (no debug info)
[/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib] small_malloc_from_free_list (no debug info)
[/usr/lib/dyld] start (no debug info)
```

I'm posting this here because the error message makes me think that it's not a `ROOT` problem, but a MacOS problem.

I did `grep -r sysctl /` which matched in various places including `/usr/bin/man:SYSCTL=/sbin/sysctl` so I checked `/usr/sbin/sysctl` and it exists.

Using macOS Ventura 13.0.1

My research online says that the problem is caused by `sysctl` being in `/sbin/` not `/usr/sbin/` but that's not my case.

Can someone please tell me what the problem is here? I don't find any reference to hadd not being available on MacOS.

Comment: Anyway, `sysctl` should be found automatically. What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: @nohillside 
`$ echo $PATH /Users/bethlong/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_1/bin:/Users/bethlong/opt/anaconda3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/condabin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PATH` variable doesn't contain `/usr/sbin` so `hadd`/`root-config` can't find it.

As a quick fix, run

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

and then execute `hadd` again.

For a longterm fix please make sure

- These two directories (`/usr/sbin` and `/sbin`) are included in `/etc/paths`
- Your shell doesn't mangle PATH somehow in the profile it loads at start

Comment: Added these to my `PATH` in my `.bash_profile` and now it works perfectly, thank you